# Photoshop CS6 - How to Use a Layer as a Cookie Cutter

Tags: select, image-processing, photoshop, layer, cut

**Software**: Photoshop CS6

**OS**: Windows 8

**Situation**: I have an image of a tree trunk on my base layer that has a birdhouse in the middle. The birdhouse has it's own layer. I want to use the birdhouse layer as a 'cookie cutter' in order to nicely cut out the shape of the birdhouse so I can put something else in it's place.

Is this even possible? To use a layer as a cutter? How can I achieve this effect? 
I tried to use the magic wand tool but the edges of the cut out were very fuzzy and choppy.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a **Clipping Mask**

Place the image (Image b) you want to cut out one layer above the birdhouse. Select the layer and right click to reveal the layer options and click "Create clipping mask." This will only display pixels in Image b that fall within the bounds of the birdhouse layer. It's a nifty feature I use a lot.